# How to download full BTC chain with limited internet

Tags: full-node, synchronization, bandwidth, mobile

I am running linux mint on a laptop with an external ssd, and want to set up a full BTC node. My problem is that I only have jetpack internet which won’t handle a full sync in one go.  I can take my time & download 50 gb each month until complete, if stopping & restarting is an option. Or any better solution anyone might have.

Answer (score 1):

Pausing and resuming will just work; simply stop the application and start it again whenever you want.

Copying the data files from a friend might be a better option, if you can.

Or set up a Blockstream sat receiver.